# Can't reach ArrayList content

Tags: java, arraylist, xstream

I've been parsing XML into ArrayList using Xsrteam. It worked but for some reason I can't reach array's content.

Classes which handle ArrayList data:

```
@XStreamAlias("BOARDS")
public class Boards {
    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "id")
    public ArrayList ids = new ArrayList();

    //region GETTERS-SETTERS
    public void setIds(ArrayList temp){
        this.ids = temp;
    }
    public List getIds(){
        return ids;
    }
//    endregion
}

@XStreamAlias("id")
class Id {

    @XStreamAlias("board")
    private String board;

    @XStreamAlias("description")
    private String description;

    @XStreamAlias("price")
    private String price;

    @XStreamAlias("shape")
    private String shape;

    @XStreamAlias("riding_level")
    private String ridingLevel;

    @XStreamAlias("riding_style")
    private String ridingStyle;

    @XStreamAlias("camber_profile")
    private String camber;

    @XStreamAlias("stance")
    private String stance;

    @XStreamAlias("picture")
    private String picture;

    <<public getters - setters here>>
}
```

How I tried to access those `getters`:

```
Boards boards = (Boards) xstream.fromXML(reader); // parse xml into array list
boards.getIds().get(0).getPrice(); //!!getPrice() cannot be resolved
```

`first` is `Object first = boards.getIds().get(0);`

Here what it looks like using debugger:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Boards` has a raw type, because of that it is unclear, what object types should be inside `ArrayList ids`. So, you should either cast result of `boards.getIds().get(0)` explicitly:

```
((Id) boards.getIds().get(0)).getPrice()
```

or generify `Boards` class:

```
public class Boards<E> {

    public List<E> ids = new ArrayList<E>();

    //region GETTERS-SETTERS
    public void setIds(ArrayList<E> temp){
        this.ids = temp;
    }
    public List<E> getIds(){
        return ids;
    }
//    endregion
}
```

You can read about generics [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: oh, as always the reason is pretty simple. Thanks for quick reply!